# Has a pilot ever been disciplined for taking a guest for a flight in a single-seat fighter aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, fighter

I recall reading of a spitfire pilot who was suspended for taking a member of the WAAF up for a jaunt to impress her. She supposedly sat in the pilot's lap throughout the short flight and they were caught when they landed and a member of the ground crew noticed her alighting. I specifically remember the author referred to her as "*a uniformed lovely*" in his recounting.

I've spent some time googling around and rummaging in my library but to no avail. Can anyone identify this *specific* incident (ideally the exact account) and/or have there been other incidents that are similar?

Comment: Does anyone seriously believe that this happened only once?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri - I guess we'll find out if/when someone posts an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the book "A Spitfire Girl" the pilot's name was Flight Lieutenant Edward Gordon Brettell DFC of "Great Escape" fame, among other things, and he was court-martialed for flying his Spitfire Mark Vb of 92 Squadron to a dance with a WAAF on his lap. Squadron Leader Tony Bartley DFC helped defend him during the court-martial.

The man was a colorful character, to say the least. In [one of the many references](http://www.hatfield-herts.co.uk/aviation/brettell.html) to him on the Internet I found this:

> He had flown his girlfriend, a WAAF based at Tangmere, in his single
> seat Spitfire to RAF Biggin Hill for a squadron party. Unfortunately
> for him, the station commander who was there when they landed took a
> dim view of his actions and reported him. Among the charges at his
> later court martial was endangering the King's aircraft (King George
> VI was then on the throne). He called upon his friend, a Battle of
> Britain ace with a Hatfield-link, Anthony Charles Bartley (41816) for
> help.
>
> Tony Bartley was acting as a test pilot for Supermarine at the time.
> He later revealed in his autobiography that he asked Jeffrey Quill
> (Supermarine's chief test pilot) and Joseph Smith (Supermarine's chief
> designer after Reginald Mitchell's death) for their help. Joe Smith
> even went so far as to draw up some mathematical equations alleged to
> prove the aircraft wasn't in any danger, which Bartley presented at
> the court martial. Although the clinching argument was when asked by
> the prosecution how he could prove it, **Bartley admitted to having
> committed an identical offence previously**. Now faced with the prospect
> of having to prosecute two badly needed officers with a war on, the
> charge was dismissed. Although Gordon Brettell was transferred away
> from the squadron.

Comment: Hey, he is a test pilot after all. It's his job to push the limits.

Comment: That was Bartley; Brettell was not a test pilot, he was just crazy. :)